# Understanding OpenSSL's Assembly version of AES decryption implementation

Tags: c, linux, assembly, openssl, aes

I am trying to understand **how OpenSSL implemented AES decryption using Assembly language** and for the same I am using **gdb debugger**.

To understand from very basic concept **how AES works - like Byte Substitute, Mix Columns OR how lookup table operations are performed.** I am using very old version of OpenSSL-0.9.8.a as it contains only one assembly file ax86-elf.s ( generated from aes-586.pl) whereas latest Openssl contains multiple files (supporting AES-NI, SSE etc).

After understanding with Old OpenSSL, I may try to look into latest OpenSSL version.

**Here is what I have done so far.**

Generated assembly code of ax86-elf.s can be found here 
https://pastebin.com/L3FsbqmK
 It has **global label AES_Td**  which points to some long data. I think those long data is the AES look up table data.

```
.globl  AES_Td
.text
.globl  _x86_AES_decrypt
.type   _x86_AES_decrypt,@function
.align  16
_x86_AES_decrypt:
    movl    %edi,       12(%esp)
...
...
    .align  64
    AES_Td:
        .long   1353184337,1353184337
        .long   1399144830,1399144830
        .long   3282310938,3282310938
        .long   2522752826,2522752826
        .long   3412831035,3412831035
        .long   4047871263,4047871263
        .long   2874735276,2874735276
        .long   2466505547,2466505547
        .long   1442459680,1442459680
```

To debug openssl, I have used gdb.

```
   gdb /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl 

    (gdb) set args enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in ciphertext2.bin -out plaintext2.txt -K 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000

(gdb) set logging on
Copying output to gdb.txt.

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8055591

(gdb) b _x86_AES_decrypt
Function "_x86_AES_decrypt" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in ciphertext2.bin -out plaintext2.txt -K 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000

Breakpoint 1, 0x08055591 in main ()

(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
__GI_getenv (name=0x8090a32 "OPENSSL_DEBUG_MEMORY") at getenv.c:35
35  getenv.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) 
__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcat.S:55
55  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcat.S: No such file or directory.

(gdb) 
__GI_getenv (name=0x8090a32 "OPENSSL_DEBUG_MEMORY") at getenv.c:36
36  getenv.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) 
__strlen_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S:43
43  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
```

Now this shows getenv.c is called, then ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S is called (although I am not able to view source code due to non-availablity).

**I am wondering this way I would be able to understand the code as it shows so many calls of functions whose source code is not available.**

So I follow this second approach, without putting any break-point at main.

```
    gdb /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl 

    (gdb) set args enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in ciphertext2.bin -out plaintext2.txt -K 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
    (gdb) set logging on
    Copying output to gdb.txt.
    (gdb) b _x86_AES_decrypt
    Function "_x86_AES_decrypt" not defined.
    Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

    Breakpoint 1 (_x86_AES_decrypt) pending.
    (gdb) run
    Starting program: /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in ciphertext2.bin -out plaintext2.txt -K 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000

    Breakpoint 1, 0xb7e57590 in _x86_AES_decrypt ()
       from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
    (gdb) s
    Single stepping until exit from function _x86_AES_decrypt,
    which has no line number information.
    0xb7e586d0 in AES_cbc_encrypt () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
    (gdb) s
    Single stepping until exit from function AES_cbc_encrypt,
    which has no line number information.

    Breakpoint 1, 0xb7e57590 in _x86_AES_decrypt ()
       from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
    (gdb) 
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function _x86_AES_decrypt,
which has no line number information.
0xb7e586d0 in AES_cbc_encrypt () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function AES_cbc_encrypt,
which has no line number information.
0xb7ea380e in aes_128_cbc_cipher () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function aes_128_cbc_cipher,
which has no line number information.
0xb7ea182d in EVP_EncryptUpdate () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function EVP_EncryptUpdate,
which has no line number information.
0xb7ea1a39 in EVP_DecryptUpdate () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function EVP_DecryptUpdate,
which has no line number information.
__memcpy_ssse3_rep () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-rep.S:111
111 ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-rep.S: No such file or directory.
```

I have following doubts -

1. **I am not able to understand where AES LOOKUP table operations are performed ? How to find them ?**
2. Why AES_cbc_encrypt, EVP_EncryptUpdate functions are called although I am performing decryption operations?
3. How to debug functions EVP_DecryptUpdate() to understand how the function is executed ? Simply putting breakpoint at the function like b EVP_DecryptUpdate is not giving any insight.

Here is what I am getting while putting breakpoint

```
(gdb) b EVP_DecryptUpdate
Breakpoint 3 at 0xb7ea19e0
(gdb) run

Breakpoint 3, 0xb7ea19e0 in EVP_DecryptUpdate ()
   from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) si
0xb7ea19e1 in EVP_DecryptUpdate () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) si
0xb7ea19e2 in EVP_DecryptUpdate () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
0xb7ea19e3 in EVP_DecryptUpdate () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
0xb7ea19e4 in EVP_DecryptUpdate () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
0xb7e372c0 in __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx ()
   from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
0xb7e372c3 in __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx ()
   from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
0xb7ea19e9 in EVP_DecryptUpdate () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 
0xb7ea19ef in EVP_DecryptUpdate () from /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
(gdb) 


EVP_DecryptUpdate() function is defined inside crypto/evp/evp_enc.c

int EVP_DecryptUpdate(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out, int *outl,
             const unsigned char *in, int inl)
{
```

**How to display the corresponding C instructions while debugging using gdb ?**

I am not sure, but it may be possible OpenSSL use various C programs as well as assembly to decrypt the AES encrypted ciphertext. How to find the flow of evaluation ?

I am using Debian linux, 32bit, gdb .

Any help to understand the above flow or any link to understand will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *How to display the corresponding C instructions while debugging using gdb ?*  There aren't any.  The asm is hand-written; it *is* the source.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for some asm debugging tips.  (Although if you build the asm with `-g`, then "source level" debugging will work; as you single-step you can see the asm source instead of disassembly.)

Comment: I didn't look at the loops themselves, but that's not the most efficient asm.  It uses a `call` without a matching return to get EIP, so it breaks the return-address predictor.  It also uses `pushf` / `cld` / `popf` for some reason, but the i386 SysV ABI guarantees that DF is clear on function entry.  (IDK if this code was written to be portable to other ABIs that don't guarantee that?  I assumed all the Windows calling conventions do.)  Also, it puts the table next to the machine code, wasting space in the iTLB.  It's better to put data in the `.rodata` section instead of mixing with code.

Comment: Looks like the code uses an `lea` to get a pointer to the base of the table in `%ebp`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, building the library with -g option allow me to enter into C source code.